# Storing checkbox values in an array and use them in a mysqli query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm currently trying around with php and mysqli and facing a little problem right now.
I have a form containing 3 checkboxes, where the user can select a mandatory field. Therefore the database contains 3 attributes (binary; 0,1). A data set can contain betwenn 0 and 3 of these attributes.

These are the checkboxes:

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">
<input type="hidden" name="attribute1" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="attribute1" value="1" /> Attribute1 <br/>
<input type="hidden" name="attribute2" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="attribute2" value="1" /> Attribute2 <br/>
<input type="hidden" name="attribute3" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="attribute3" value="1" /> Attribute3 <br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So the goal is that if I check attribute1, the result must contain all data sets with attribute1 = 1, but they can also contain attribute2 = 1 & attribute3 = 1.

When I check attribute1 right now I get the results for a1 = 1, a2= 0 and a3 = 0.

So I think this could be solved by using an array which only stores the checked checkboxes, so if attribute1 and attribute3 are checked, it should be $array = [attribute1 = 1, attribute3 = 1].

My current mysqli query:

```
$strAttribute1 = $_POST["attribute1"];
$strAttribute2 = $_POST["attribute2"];
$strAttribute3 = $_POST["attribute3"];

$query = "SELECT name, beschreibung
          FROM uebersicht
          WHERE attribute1 = $strAttribute1
          AND attribute2 = $strAttribute2
          AND attribute3 = $strAttribute3";
```

As a solution I thought about a query like:

```
... WHERE " . $array ."
```

Unfortunately I'm stuck at this point, which is the proper way to solve it with an array? Or is that the wrong idea?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there wouldn't be much point, unless you're going to be adding dozens/hundreds of checkboxes... you'd spent more time writing code to take apart/build arrays and strings than you would by just defining your 3 variables... and as written, you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: How would you define the variables? I tried an if loop to check if the box is checked otherwise the variable wont be set. After it checked the state of all 3 boxes the variables are imploded to a string which is used in a query. Unfortunately it doesn't work either.
So do you have a code example which could solve it?
I noticed you recommendation on the sql injection already yesterday and I'll take care of it, so I'll take care of it later but want to get a working query first.
So do you have a code suggestion?
Regards

Comment: assuming your field names are consisten, thent `for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { $params[] = "attribute{$i} = '{$_POST["attribute$i"]}'"; }`, which gives you an (inject vulnerable) array of key=value pairs you can implode however you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marc B, it helped me a lot and now the query works superb! When the whole form is done, I'll rework it injection safe!
Regards